# My PC doesn't boot up normally and shows several BSOD errors

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, bsod

My Laptop, a Dell Inspiron 7520s running Windows 10 x64 has stopped booting up normally. I get errors like:

- "KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED"
- "Thread stuck on device driver"
- " Page fault in nonpaged area :-dxgmms1.sys"
- "system service exception:- win32base.sys"
- "kernel security check failure"
- "Driver IRQL not less or equal :-dxgmms1.sys"
- "MEMORY MANAGEMENT"
- "Critical process died"

The errors listed above appear randomly. When I boot, it shows the blue screen listing any one of the errors, and when restarted, it shows another.

I am unable to find any solution to the problem since most of the solutions require a normal boot to diagnose and I am only able to access Safe Mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing it could be bad RAM. If there is more than one stick of RAM installed you could try different combinations to see if it makes a difference. Alternatively, you could use another PC to make a bootable MemTest86 CD or USB stick.

Comment: There's only one 4gb Ram stick. I'll try the memtest86 once and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I tried Memtest86 through a bootable USB. It ran few tests which showed no errors. What should I do now ?

Comment: You need to run the test for several hours to be reasonably sure there isn't a memory issue. If the test still passes then you'll need to look into other possibilities. Your Windows installation could be corrupted, in which case you could try using the Windows 10 media creation tool to create a bootable drive/disc that you can use to do a startup repair. It's possible your hard drive is failing and is the root cause of any corruption  so you might want to check that out.

Comment: If you are able to run in safe mode you should be able to use a tool like HWMonitor to check the hard drive SMART status

Comment: I'll try it today. Something which I have noticed is that my hard drive area gets too heated up. Thanks

Comment: I found that the problem was with my AMD graphics card driver. When I replaced windows 10 by windows 7 and installed all the drivers, I got the blue screen but with atikmdag.sys. I looked up and when I removed the AMD drivers it worked fine. So now I've reinstalled windows 10. I also realised that the driver problem is being faced by many who have the same laptop as perhaps neither Dell nor AMD has correct driver. I myself tried many different drivers from AMD as well as Dell's website but I still got the BSOD every time I refreshed the device list in device manager.